# TFS 2013 - How to import a global workflow with both "Fields" and "GlobalLists"

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I'm trying to use "**Global Workflow**" feature of TFS to have maintainable Work Item Customization.

Only resources I could've found is these two from msdn:

- [Manage Global Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg534717.aspx)
- [Customize global workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg534720.aspx)

There are two problems I couldn't find a solution:

From the definitions I have a globalWorkflow.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GLOBALWORKFLOW>
<FIELDS>
    <FIELD name="Global Field" refname="Namespace.GlobalField" type="String">
        <REQUIRED />
    </FIELD>
</FIELDS>
<GLOBALLISTS>
    <GLOBALLIST name="Years">
        <LISTITEM value="2014" />
        <LISTITEM value="2015" />
      </GLOBALLIST>
</GLOBALLISTS>  
</GLOBALWORKFLOW>
```

1. I can import globalworkflow.xml either having only "Fields" tag or only "GlobalLists" tag but not both. If I try to import with both, like shown above, it gives a xml validation error indicating the second tag is not an acceptable child element of "GlobalWorkflow" tag.

   If I put "GlobalLists" second, "GlobalLists" is the invalid child element, "Fields" tag is invalid if it's written as second element.
2. If it is imported including "Fields" tag, after import of global workflow; I can see the defined field in the WI Field Explorer of Power Tools but not in the definitions of the work items or in any combo for Field Selection, only in Work Item Field Explorer(not in Layout Tab, Workflow Tab or Fields Tab of work item).

***MSDN vaguely explained the process like:***

> If you specify a field that is not currently defined for the team
>   project or the collection, the field is created when the global
>   workflow is imported.

I can assume, global workflow xml only saves the field and then you still have to define the same field in the fields tab of the work item to use it in Layout tab and Workflow tab. TFS only prevents another field creation in the same name and also implements the defined field rules. This logic, is not nice imho but still can be acceptable.

But there is still a problem with that logic to be true, because if I import global workflow with only globallist definitions, defined globallists are not seen in the global list designer screen or not in combo fields like "allowedvalues" rule options.

I'm using `witadmin -importglobalworkflow /collection:"url" /f:"filepath"` command and though I want my global workflow definition can be used from all my Team Project Collection

**Expected Result**
I want to be able to import a global workflow with both "Fields" and "GlobalLists" elements and after import operation, in a work item I should be able to see these definitions like the way I've created using Power tools.

**UPDATE:**
1 is solved: one global workflow can not include both "fields" and "globallists" elements.
MSDN didn't specifically explained it but the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg534716.aspx) include only seperate xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the globalist into a separate file, and import it with the command

```
witadmin importgloballist /collection:"http://MyServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /f:Directory/globallist.xml
```

Reference for globalists here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194977.aspx

Comment: Thanks but like I wrote, I want to use global workflow, not globallist.

Comment: Importing a globallist as I described makes it part of the global workflow. As in your own update, you cannot do both at the same time.

Comment: your example is for globallist import operation and not related to global workflow afaik. please include an article if it is shown anywhere. I know, I can use globallist but I'm trying to learn how to use it using a global workflow.

Comment: Try it. Use importgloballist as I recommended, and then do an exportglobalworkflow with the /exportgloballist switch.

Comment: Also, to your second question that is expected behavior. You still have to add the field to the witd form element in order for it to show up. I think you might be trying to use global fields for something they aren't intended for. They are intended to be fields that you access/update programatically (like MS Project integration fields), not fields that display on work item forms. Even if you define it as a global field, you still have to add it to the witd.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I wished at least. I'll try the globallist operation first thing tomorrow. thanks again

Comment: Yes, I've tried what you've suggested. It's exactly as you said. The switch is "/exportgloballists". I thought globalworkflow could be used as a template but it's only for integration purposes I guess as you've described. Thanks a lot. But I think, the lack of globallist import eventhough the acceptable "<globallists>" definition through "importglobalworkflow" operation is buggy. I still couldn't figure out why importglobalworkflow supports "globallists" tag, if it is only can be done through "importgloballist" cmd.

Comment: I totally agree. Both the command and the documentation are misleading.